# Changing the NavigationBar tint colour

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

there are numerous entries on this subject all with very different answers and given up as all that I have tired don't work.

If I want to alter the Navigation Bar tint colour when the page loads why won't this code suffice?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor greenColor];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }
```

Comment: Please read the tag wikis for the tags you use. The only tag (xcode) you used is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Is your viewController actually placed inside a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: What is the issue in this ? ? Add this code in ViewWillappear

Comment: Apologies for the tags and have put it in viewWillAppear - many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see no reason that code won't suffice.

I just tested it on a new Master-Detail Application. It works perfectly!

I might not have solved your problem, but this line of code looks fine.